# Induction to prove that for all integers n ≥ 1.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image: https://i.imgur.com/EjCXmCd.png]

It says we add $(n + 1)^2$ on both sides of this relation and get ......

Then on the left side, it only says (n+1) over the Σ and not (n+1)^2 . Do you folks know why?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k = 1+2+\cdots+n$.  If you add $n+1$ to this you get $1+2+\cdots+n+(n+1)$ which is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}k$

Comment: $(n+1)+\dfrac{n(n+1)}2=(n+1)(1+\dfrac n2)=(n+1)\dfrac{n+2}2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Hi, just saw that I posted the wrong question. Just look at the picture once again.

Comment: @Henry Sorry, got the wrong question. Just trying to understand what they are trying to do. Really dont understand what happens with (n+1)^2 on the left side.

Comment: $(n+1)^2+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}k^2$

Comment: (n+1)^2 is the (n+1)st term, so the expression on top of the Σ changes to just n+1. I am wrong? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @MatrhWonder00:  I think your understanding is correct

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: You’re welcome.  I took the liberty of editing to say we add $(n+1)^\color{red}2$ to both sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(n+1)^2+\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2$$